# Regex: Match every character between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a way to match **every** character between two strings.

For example, for the given string `abc--def--ghi`, I want the regex to match `d`, `e`, and `f`.

I've tried using the following regex `(?<=--)(.*)(?=--)`, however this matches *all* the characters between `--` (`def`), whereas I need to match *every* character between `--`.

`s.match(/--(.*?)--/)[1].split("")` doesn't work as I need to do this without splitting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the programming language? Also, what is the expected result if you had `abc--def--ghi--jkl`?

Comment: Would it be possible to first match _all_ characters and then just split the resulting groups?

Comment: Perhaps `(.)*` instead of `(.*)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's Javascript

Comment: @Souperman No, that will not be possible

Comment: In JS, it *is* possible, you do not need to use a single regex. `s.match(/--(.*?)--/)[1].split("")`

Comment: @0x5453 No, this doesn't work

Comment: You may (ab)use the regex like `s.match(/(?<=--(?:(?!--).)*).(?=(?:(?!--).)*--)/gs)`, but this is really not a good idea. You need to add the JS and the "no `split`" requirement to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True. However, I will need to do this without splitting. Can you explain your last solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As for your question "what is the expected result if you had `abc--def--ghi--jkl`?" In my case, there wouldn't be a case where such input could be provided.

Comment: Ok, that is important as overlapping patterns would be impossible to handle in this scenario. Well, next to impossible.

Comment: @CherryDT In the particular scenario, I need to pass a regex to a function which replaces a regex match with something else. The requirement is to pass a regex so that every character will be replaced. Which is why split can't be used.

Comment: @yankolo What is this function? How does it define what it replaces with? I'm asking because in case of a regular `replace` call, you could pass a function as replacement: ```s.replace(/--(.*?)--/, (_, x) => `--${'*'.repeat(x.length)}--`)``` would replace each character by `*` for instance.

Comment: @CherryDT The function accepts a string for the regex. I see what you mean. I believe that your approach is better. I didn't know that you can pass a replacer function to `replace()`. I am able to update the design of the function, so that's good. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, using the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex engine, you can achieve what you want without additional split step using

```js
/(?<=--(?:(?!--).)*).(?=(?:(?!--).)*--)/gs
/(?<=--[^-]*(?:-(?!-)[^-]*)*).(?=[^-]*(?:-(?!-)[^-]*)*--)/gs
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tby2J1/2) (the [second variant](https://regex101.com/r/Tby2J1/3) is the same regex as the first one, but more efficient as it follows the "unroll-the-loop" principle). *Details*:

- `(?<=--(?:(?!--).)*)` - a location immediately preceded by `--` and then any one or more (as many as possible) chars, each of which does not start a `--` char sequence
- `.` - any single char
- `(?=(?:(?!--).)*--)` - immediately followed by any one or more (as many as possible) chars, each of which does not start a `--` char sequence, and then `--`.

The `s` flag enables `.` to match any char including line break chars that `.` does not match by default.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can you please explain why you said (in one of your other comments) that this solution is not a good idea?

Comment: @yankolo Backtracking step amount with this regex is much bigger than with a simpler `--(.*?)--`. I added a more efficient version, but an unachored lookbehind as the first construct in a regex pattern is still computationally expensive.

Comment: Speaking of performance, how much worse is it?

Comment: @yankolo That should be checked in the target environment.